# Why can't I run a simple program locally?

Tags: bash, compilation, local

Any program I try to run on my computer compiles without error, but when I run it, there is no output. This is the code for a simple helloWorld.c program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

    printf("%s", "Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

Here is what the bash shell looks like:

caden@LAPTOP-R0C0BLHD ~$ ls

helloWorld.c

caden@LAPTOP-R0C0BLHD ~$
gcc -o hello helloWorld.c

caden@LAPTOP-R0C0BLHD ~$ ls

hello.exe  helloWorld.c

caden@LAPTOP-R0C0BLHD ~$ ./hello.exe

caden@LAPTOP-R0C0BLHD ~$

```
                  Any idea why there is no output?
```

Here are all the things I have tried:

Running the executable with ./hello

Using the command prompt instead of a bash shell

Running a different file

Using a notepad++ plugin called npExec instead of a bash shell

Debugging with gdb, it Exited with code: 0xffffffff

Reinstalling MinGW, restarting computer

Resetting my PATH environment variable to the default

Comment: This question isn't related to `bash` but I'd try appending a `\n` to the `Hello World`

Comment: If your program is called `helloWorld.c` you should use that name when compiling, i.e. `gcc -o hello helloWorld.c`. Also, please show ouput of `DIR` command in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `#include <stdio.h>`. So the final code should be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%s", "Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I included <stdio.h> and still no output unfortunately.

Comment: Hi @CKirb21 in your example you are missing a space. Please copy a paste mine and it will work.

Comment: Unfortunately @imjoseangel this did not solve the problem, thanks for the suggestion though.